# How to tell Angular where to load font-face files from, for exemple, from /static folder

Tags: angular, sass

I'm using `ng build` with the `--deploy-url` command, to tell Angular where to load files from. I'm deploying angular as part of a Spring-Boot war, inside folder I created called /static, at root level of the war. My .js and .html files are found correctly, but all @font-face files are not being found (see picture).[image: 404 for font-face files]

Is there any way to tell Angular where to load these files from, I'd like to not have to leave them in root. By the way, I'm using SCSS if that matters. Thanks

Comment: [This](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/include-font-awesome.md#using-sass) might help. How to load font awesome into angular cli

Comment: @LLai, thanks, but the problem is not loading the font. The problem is I want to have it read from a folder called /static at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use font awesome is to `npm intall` it into your Angular project, Then, double check that the resource URL ([CDN](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/)) is inside your angular.cli file under `'scripts'`. If you want Font Awesome locally available, download it from their [website](http://fontawesome.io/), place it inside the assets folder, and put the local path to it inside your angular.cli file under `'scripts'`.

Sass would not have anything to do with a 404 not found error, if it was affecting it there would be a different error.

Comment: FussinHussin, the problem is not installing or obtaining the font, the problem is that I don't want the artifacts in root of my war file. I want them in /static folder, but Angular is not finding them. --deploy-url tells angular to load .js files from non-standard location, I'm looking for something similar for @font-face files. Thanks!